# How could an induced magnetosphere be created at Mars for terraforming?

Tags: mars, radiation, terraforming, magnetic-field, magnetosphere

In the long run Mars needs a magnetic field to keep a thick atmosphere and for radiation shielding, if humanity were to terraform it. Starting a dynamo in Mars' core seems forever impossible, but a magnetic field could instead be induced by the Solar wind.

Venus has [a naturally induced](http://www.astrobio.net/topic/solar-system/venus/a-magnetic-surprise-from-venus/) magnetic field. Could an ionosphere be densified to create a much stronger magnetic field? For example by bringing material from Phobos and ionising it above Mars?

Comment: *In the long run Mars needs a magnetic field to keep a thick atmosphere.*  Although this seems to be common knowledge, it doesn't explain Venus.  *If* we are ever able to terraform Mars and thicken its atmosphere considerably, then the speed at which impatient humans thicket the atmosphere is surely orders of magnitude larger than the speed at which the atmosphere escapes.

Comment: @gerrit I added radiation shielding as another motive.

Comment: @gerrit - There is some evidence that Venus is still volcanically active which helps add to the atmosphere, whereas Mars is not.  This does not fully resolve the issue, but volcanic activity would help (though I am not sure if volcanos alone can explain the absurdly thick atmosphere compared with Earth... ).

Comment: @honeste_vivere Venus is much larger than Mars, almost as large as Earth, which would suggest size is a far more important factor than the magnetic field.

Comment: @gerrit - That's not what the results from [MAVEN](https://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/maven/main/index.html) seem to suggest, but perhaps I missed something in those articles.

Comment: @honeste_vivere MAVEN is studying Mars, not Venus.  It is true that most (but not all) MAVEN scientists consider the magnetic field to be of critical importance to the loss of the Mars atmosphere, but any model of atmospheric escape or retention ought to work on each of Mercury, Venus, Mars, Earth, Ganymede, and Titan, with all their different temperatures, sizes, magnetic fields, and atmospheres.  I'm sure MAVEN scientists would be more than happy to send MAVEN-like instruments to all the planets/moons I listed ☺

Comment: You may wish to take a gander at http://space.stackexchange.com/questions/2423/how-would-it-be-possible-to-kick-start-marss-magnetic-field/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The premise of the question is incorrect. If you were able to terraform Mars on a human civilization time scale in the first place, then you can replenish the atmosphere, if you like, at a rate several orders of magnitude faster than the rate of loss to the solar wind. Or you can simply ignore that loss, since it won't be noticeable for many millions of years.

The terraformed atmosphere, assuming Earth sea-level density or even mile-high density, would provide ample radiation protection.

You don't need a magnetosphere to terraform Mars.

Comment: I do not in any way disagree. Just noting the flood of news which *seems to be* about NASA's interest in the protection Mars' atmosphere with a magnetic field. See for example Phys.org's [NASA proposes a magnetic shield to protect Mars' atmosphere](https://phys.org/news/2017-03-nasa-magnetic-shield-mars-atmosphere.html) and this lovely NASA graphic: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZ79Z.jpg

Comment: I've asked a [follow-up question](http://space.stackexchange.com/q/20596/12102).

Answer (score 8):

The way to solve this problem has recently been proposed by NASA. Put a magnet on the L1 Legrange point (between Mars and the Sun) of about 2 Tesla. This is what it looks like:

[image: Magnetic Mars shield]

At present, atmospheric loss on Mars is balanced to some degree by volcanic outgassing from Mars interior and crust. This contributes to a surface atmosphere that is about 6 mbar in air pressure (less than 1% that at sea level on Earth). As a result of the magnet, Mars atmosphere would naturally thicken over time, this would include an average increase of about 4 °C (~7 °F), which would be enough to melt the carbon dioxide ice in the northern polar ice cap. This would trigger a greenhouse effect, warming the atmosphere further and causing the water ice in the polar caps to melt.

This is what it looks like now:
[image]

Source: https://phys.org/news/2017-03-nasa-magnetic-shield-mars-atmosphere.html#jCp