# Are artificial magnetic fields used or proposed to be used to shield astronauts from charged, high energy radiation?

Tags: magnetic-field, shielding, cosmic-radiation, magnetosphere

If not for the earth's magnetic field our atmosphere would be bombarded by high energy plasma (ionized gas) from the sun and other space sources.

Much of these particles have [more energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmic_ray) than the protons accelerated in the large hadron collider.

At very high altitudes and orbital altitudes this protection is less and when space travel takes astronauts out of range of earth's magnetic field there is no shielding or protection.

Does the International Space Station or other craft have an artificial magnetic field to protect its astronauts? If not are there plans for implementation?

Comment: Don't forget to delete your [cross post on Aviation.SE](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/40903/52)

Comment: @DanPichelman not familiar with this rule.  Space Exploration SE is the more appropriate fit.  How best to draw attention here for the Aviation readers that may be interested?

Comment: I agree Space Exploration is a better fit for this.  See [this question on Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/218240) regarding cross posting.  I'm not sure how to attract the Aviation readers (but it wouldn't surprise me if a lot of them, like you and I, read both).

Comment: Extreamly strong and large magnetic fields would be necessary. To generate a shield effect like the earth's magnetic field would require a huge mass and energy.

Comment: related, but not a duplicate since it is restricted to NASA research;  [Is NASA doing research on “mini-magnetospheres” to protect crew from radiation in space?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/20596/12102)

Comment: No current spacecraft uses magnetic shielding. As the other comments indicate, research is being done.