# Why don't astronauts/ships/stations carry portable 'magnetospheres'?

Tags: magnetic-field, cosmic-radiation, design-alternative

As I understand it, cosmic radiation is one of the biggest dangers/problems to space exploration. Some cursory research seems to suggest that it wouldn't take very strong magnetic fields to deflect this radiation; a 1T field can be generated with less than 5A (though area of the field would be the biggest question).

So is there a reason a space station or other body wouldn't just generate their own magnetosphere to deflect this radiation?

Comment: I have a question in return: what research have you done in this area that would suggest generating a 1T field would be a) doable, and b) enough?

Comment: A superconducting one Tesla magnetic field generator would be far too heavy for an astronaut to carry.

Comment: related "mini-magnetosphere" question: [Is NASA doing research on “mini-magnetospheres” to protect crew from radiation in space?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/20596/12102)

Comment: To add to @Uwe 's answer, I will refer you to a paper, titled 'Active magnetic radiation shielding system analysis and key
technologies'. If you read through it you will have been better understanding of the active shielding. http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.lssr.2014.12.004