# Electricity for magnetic shield at Mars L1 Lagrange point

Tags: mars

[NASA](https://phys.org/news/2017-03-nasa-magnetic-shield-mars-atmosphere.html#jCp) says that it can build a magnetic dipole shield at the Mars L1 Lagrange Point, but how do they support the electricity?

Comment: Related (links to same article): [Is NASA doing research on “mini-magnetospheres” to protect crew from radiation in space?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/20596/12102) I'm not sure that NASA "says they are doing it" as much as they simply hosted an event for a group of people where this (among other things) was discussed. Your question is certainly valid though. Here's the paper that the article links to: https://www.hou.usra.edu/meetings/V2050/pdf/8250.pdf

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They haven't got that far yet.

This article says scientists have *proposed a method* for creating an artificial magnetic field. The next steps are:

1. Design a system that can generate the magnetic field required.
2. Calculate how much power that system needs.

And then, if the result of 1. and 2. is a feasible system and not e.g. far too large for us to launch into orbit, they can start thinking about how that power will be provided.