# Could the Moon keep an atmosphere?

Tags: the-moon, planetary-science, atmosphere, terraforming

When we think of terraforming a body in our galaxy [Mars gets lots of consideration](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mars+terraforming) as the closest potential body.  But what about the Moon?

It is currently beyond our ability to add an atmosphere to a planet or a moon, but it is not impossible, and will likely be done in the future.

If we add an atmosphere to Earth's Moon, how stable would it be? Would the Earth's Gravity steal it? Would the [Earth's magnetic field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth%27s_magnetic_field) protect it?

Comment: Question inspired by a VERY wrong answer to a recent question. You know who you are, thanks for the inspiration.

Comment: My knowledge is limited, but the problem is mass. The moon doesn't have enough mass to maintain an atmosphere.

Comment: @JamesJenkins: I was wondering how long it would be before someone did something about that particular answer...

Comment: @PearsonArtPhoto and now I'm curious...

Comment: @JanDvorak: Let's just say a person who should have known better though that http://space.stackexchange.com/q/12556/25 was about the Moon...

Comment: The Van Allen-belts are much below the Moon orbit, so it wouldn't protect.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

It can keep an atmosphere, and [in fact does](https://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/LADEE/news/lunar-atmosphere.html#.VjtdQ0ZlxNU). The atmosphere is something akin to a high grade Earth-based vacuum. But that's probably not what you are looking for.

What would happen with an Earth sized atmosphere on the Moon? A lot of really interesting things would happen actually. First of all, in longest days of the night, the atmosphere might freeze. It would also have a high wind volume, at the day/night terminator. It would lose a lot of its atmosphere (See [this Physics Question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/31909/why-is-titan-able-to-maintain-an-atmosphere-and-not-luna)) due to Solar Wind and simple lose by having too much energy.

Bottom line - the atmosphere would stay - but only for maybe 1000 years (See [this article](http://www.universetoday.com/121140/could-we-terraform-the-moon/)). Domes are probably the best way for the foreseeable future on the Moon.

To illustrate this, Wikipedia provides a [really neat chart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atmospheric_escape) showing atmospheric particles that would stick vs temperature and size.

[image: Chart illustrating what molecules will stay vs temperature and size]

Comment: Couldn't the Moon get an ionosphere that somewhat protects it against the Solar wind, like Venus? And wind speeds that super rotates the atmosphere relative to the Sun much faster, again as the weather on tardy Venus, than the Moon itself turns, to even out the day/night temperatures. 60% of the Moon's mass is oxygen, so while the varieties of potential volatiles is limited (no carbon or nitrogen), there's at least no lack of elemental raw material to refill a breathable atmosphere as it outgasses. The mass of Earth's atmosphere is but a millionth of the planet's mass.

Comment: The Solar wind is a less serious effect, which main results in smaller particles. Smaller particles are easier to float away through normal processes.

Comment: But O2 isn't that very light, and there's a refill potential anyway, lasting evolutionary times. Antelopic animals in herds could breathe and breed and jump high, and graze on fertilized fungi, on such a managed lunatic world made up.

Comment: O2 is still too light enough for the moon. See my latest edit. It could be refilled, but Xenon is really the mass of particle required to stay on the Moon without replenishment.

Comment: I think the day time temperature of the moon can reach ~400K, so even the Xenon  would tend to get enough energy to escape.  I suspect would be a slow process (millions of years?) but not indefinite.

Comment: Yeah, the high temperature range for the moon makes that difficult. Still...

Comment: The Universetoday article says: "The enormous gravity of the Earth would pull the Moon’s oceans around the planet with 20 meter tides." I am so sorry, but I don't think an article deserves citate which contains such statements :-(

Comment: That would assume that it had an ocean, and I don't think that sounds unreasonable at all... If you have doubts, feel free to open a question on that specific point.

Comment: Probably moon can be used to purify air and get high concentration Xeon. :|

Comment: The linked article doesn't tell that an atmosphere would stay only for a thousand years. Where did you get that information from ?

Comment: Just redirect a comet every now and then. How much mass would need to be replenished? If breathable atmosphere is too much, then thinner one to alleviate regolith dust issues.

Answer (score 15):

PearsonArtPhoto covers the basic issue, which is that light molecules move so fast that they reach lunar escape velocity.

The average speed of the molecules of a particular gas [is proportional to the square root of (temperature in Kelvin divided by molecular mass)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-mean-square_speed).

**I propose a couple of gases with a molecular weight higher than xenon (mw 54)** that might be able to sustain an atmosphere on the Moon, given that there is very little xenon in the Solar System.

I think the chances of terraforming the Moon with an atmosphere are very slim, but it's an interesting thought experiment.

**Butane (mw 58.)** Made of abundant elements. May decompose to lighter hydrocarbons over time, especially if interacting with hydrogen from the solar wind. Butenes or heavier, more unsaturated hydrocarbons (such as benzene) might last longer.

**Chlorine Cl<sub>2</sub> (mw 71.)** Not one of the top ten most common elements in the Solar System, so would need to be specifically mined, or imported (Earth seawater is about 2% chlorine by mass.) Would be stable on its own, but would oxidise rocks and thus leave the atmosphere if the rocks were oxygen deficient. Forms a number of gaseous oxides, but these are unstable with respect to decomposition to chlorine and oxygen, so would not accumulate. Would react with hydrogen from the solar wind to form hydrogen chloride, which has a lower molecular mass.

---

EDIT 1: according to Wikipedia, the solar wind is a mass flow of about $10^{9} \frac{kg}{s}$, most of which is hydrogen. At Earth's orbital radius of $150 \cdot 10^{6} km$, this is just:

$$\frac{10^{9}}{4\cdot\pi\cdot(150 \cdot 10^{6})^2} = 3.54\cdot 10^{-9} \frac{kg}{km^2 \cdot s}$$

or $0.11 \frac{kg}{km^2 \cdot year}$. The Moon's radius is 1740 km, so it presents a $9.511 \cdot 10^6 km^2$ surface to the solar wind. The total hydrogen received by the moon from the solar wind is therefore about $3.367 \cdot 10^{-2} \frac {kg}{s}$ so the replenishment rate of chlorine Cl<sub>2</sub> that has been converted to HCl would be quite trivial, in comparison to the unimaginably large task of putting a chlorine atmosphere on the Moon in the first place. I'm surprised this number is as small as it is.

Photodissociation of Cl<sub>2</sub> into two Cl· radicals (which each have a lower mass than CO<sub>2</sub>) may be a far more significant mechanism of loss of chlorine, but I don't know how to quantify it.

EDIT 2: another possibility is **sulphur dioxide SO<sub>2</sub> (mw 64.)** This is probably chemically stabler than either of my previous proposals. There's also a possible non-intentional source for it: If massive building programs on the Moon were undertaken using [sulphur concrete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sulfur_concrete), it might degrade in the presence of oxygen to SO<sub>2</sub>. Sulphur concrete is similar to regular concrete in that it contains aggregate, but molten sulphur is used as a binder instead of traditional cement.

Comment: Wouldn't the butane photodissociate badly?

Comment: @LorenPechtel stability of butane is an issue, I already mentioned that. But chlorine photodissociates much more than hydrocarbons, partly because it is coloured, and partly because of its lower bond strength, see http://www.cem.msu.edu/~reusch/OrgPage/bndenrgy.htm and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bond-dissociation_energy

Comment: I posted http://space.stackexchange.com/questions/12597/could-we-fly-on-the-moon-in-xenon with a focus on Xenon as it is a noble gas, but I would encourage you to post an answer based on the gas of your choice.

Comment: @James - I assume this is a consequence of solar system formation. In other words, the temperature differences in the protoplanetary disk. I can't find the temperature charts but that may be why xenon is more rare in certain parts of the solar system.

Comment: @steveverrill Wow--I would have thought butane would break down easier than chlorine.

Comment: @spacer Xenon is rare in the solar system for the same reason it is rare throughout the universe. All elements other than hydrogen are made by nuclear fusion, and this process rarely gets as far as (moderately) heavy elements like xenon. There are many anomalies, but generally the heavier an element is, the rarer it is. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abundance_of_the_chemical_elements

Comment: @steveverrill and after introducing SO2 atmosphere we would rename Moon to Stinky :).

Comment: @MatasVaitkevicius - The rotten eggs stinky one is H2S, not SO2. However, I wouldn't say that any of them - including chlorine - would qualify as "terraforming" the Moon.

Comment: Chlorine is out--it doesn't matter if the rocks are oxygen-deficient, the chlorine will take oxygen's place.  You can't have a chlorine atmosphere until you have chlorinated all available rock and chlorinated the oxygen that was driven out.  Note that this requires 2x the chlorine as there was oxygen.

Comment: @LorenPechtel Not so. Fluorine would displace oxygen, but chlorine and oxygen are very similar in reactivity. With Silicon and Aluminium, Oxygen will displace Chlorine, not the other way round. The reactions `2 AlCl3 + 3 H2O -> Al2O3 + 6 HCl` and `SiCl4 + 2 H2O -> SiO2 + 4 HCl` are widely known to proceed in the forward direction. Following your comment, I just checked at http://www.crct.polymtl.ca/reacweb.htm and found that reactions involving elemental oxygen/chlorine proceed (in the direction of negative deltaG) as follows: `2 AlCl3 + 1.5 O2 -> Al2O3 + 3 Cl2` and `SiCl4 + O2 -> SiO2 + 2Cl2`

Comment: @LevelRiverSt Color me surprised--I thought the chlorine reaction proceeded, just nowhere near as fast as the fluorine one.

Comment: @LorenPechtel Oxygen's true thermodynamic reactivity is masked by its weird electronic structure, which presents a significant kinetic barrier to reaction https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triplet_oxygen . That's why chlorine and hydrogen peroxide will bleach organic material at ambient temperature, but oxygen doesn't react until combustion temperatures around 250C. Despite the fact that the heat of formation of CCl4 is less than half that of CO2.

Comment: @LorenPechtel It is usually helpful to look at [the electronegativity table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronegativity#Pauling_electronegativity) to get a general sense about which element displaces which. Oxygen has higher electronegativity on the Pauling's scale than chlorine (3.44 for oxygen vs 3.16 for chlorine), which means that, according to that scale, it is a stronger oxidizer. Disclaimer: it is a crude comparison that ignores a lot of, sometimes essential, details. For example, different possible oxidation states.

Answer (score 4):

A couple of points not mentioned:

1. The Moon did have an atmosphere back when it had a lava ocean.  It lasted probably 70 million years or so, and I believe was about 100-1000 Pascals, or slightly less than  to slightly more than the atmospheric pressure on Mars.  There are a number of different estimates for the density and age of the lunar atmosphere.
2. The Moon is full of unreduced iron,  so adding oxygen to the atmosphere will cause it to react with the iron, creating iron oxide.  Rust, in other words.  So you will need even more oxygen, and the moon would begin to turn red in the iron-rich regions.

Reference: [Was There an Early Habitability Window for Earth's Moon?](https://www.liebertpub.com/doi/10.1089/ast.2018.1844)
Reference: [A Model of the Primordial Lunar Atmosphere[2](https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.07501)

Comment: This answer would be improved by the addition of references.

Comment: Wrong unit? Atmospheric pressure on Mars is about 0.006 bar.

Comment: Thank you.  Corrections made for both points.  Yes, the unit should be Pascals, not Bar.  Also, I added additional range and uncertainty information, as I don't think the numbers are still all that well constrained in the literature.  The numbers I posted would be near the minimum values.  Other estimates have  the duration as long as 70 million years.

Answer (score 3):

If I remember correctly, Stephen Baxter's novel Moonseed (1998) explores this question and answers yes, it could maintain an atmosphere sufficient to support human life on the surface for a couple of hundred years before it attrited away. Hardly definitive, but he's no slouch when it comes to research.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moonseed_(novel)